# Conjectured closed form of $\int\limits_0^1 \frac{\ln y \operatorname{Li}_2 (-y)}{1-y^2} \, dy$

Tags: ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, integration, special-functions, polylogarithms

Let's state with $\psi^{(1)}$ the trigamma. Calculate the order:
$$\mathcal{S} = \sum_{n=1}^\infty (-1)^{n-1} (\psi^{(1)}(n))^2$$
(Cornel Ioan Valean)

I uploaded this question here https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2412715/1295548 and https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2411733/1295548 from my old account

$$
\psi_1(z) = -\int\limits_0^1 \frac{x^{z-1} \ln x}{1-x} \, dx
$$

\begin{align}
(\psi_1(z))^2 & =\left( -\int\limits_0^1 \frac{x^{z-1}\ln x}{1-x} \, dx \right) \left( -\int\limits_0^1 \frac{y^{z-1}\ln y}{1-y} \, dy \right) = \int\limits_0^1 \int\limits_0^1 \frac{(xy)^{z-1} \ln x\ln y}{(1-x)(1-y)} \, dx \, dy \\[8pt]
& \sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}  (-1)^{n-1} (\psi_1(n))^2 = \sum_{n=1}^{+\infty} ( (\psi_1 (2n-1))^2-(\psi_1(2n))^2)
\end{align}

$$=\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty} \int\limits_0^1 \int\limits_0^1 \frac{( (xy)^{2n-2}-(xy)^{2n-1} ) \ln x\ln y}{(1-x) (1-y)} \, dx \, dy = \int\limits_0^1 \int\limits_0^1 \frac{(1-xy)\ln x\ln y}{xy(1-x)(1-y)}\cdot \frac{(xy)^2}{1-(xy)^2} \, dx \, dy $$

$$=\int\limits_0^1 \int\limits_0^1 \frac{\ln x\ln y}{(1-x) (1-y)} \cdot \frac{xy}{1+xy} \, dx \, dy = -\frac{1}{6} \int\limits_0^1 \frac{6 \operatorname{Li}_2 (-y)+\pi^2 y}{1-y^2} \ln y \, dy $$

$$=-\frac{\pi ^{2}}{6}\int\limits_0^1 \frac{y}{1-y^2}\ln y \, dy - \int\limits_0^1 \frac{\ln y\operatorname{Li}_2 (-y)}{1-y^2} \, dy = \frac{\pi^2}{6} \cdot \frac{\pi^2}{24}-\int\limits_0^1 \frac{\ln y \operatorname{Li}_2 (-y)}{1-y^2} \, dy $$

Comment: This question has a serious flaw. The final row says $S=\frac{\pi^2}{144}-I$ being $S$ the sum and $I$ the integral. The correct relationship is $$S=\frac{\pi^2}{48}+I$$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $J$ be the integral to be computed. The following solution was written so that the parallel "clean" formula or a related integral $J_1$ (with no minus sign under the blue dilogarithm) is also mentioned:
$$
\tag{$*$}
J_1 =
\int_0^1\log y\; \color{blue}{\operatorname{Li}_2(y)}\;\frac1{1-y^2}\; dy
=\bbox[yellow]{\ -\frac 1{192}\pi^4\ }\ .
$$
We record formulas for its "pieces":
$$
\begin{aligned}
J_{11} &=
\int_0^1\log y\; \color{blue}{\operatorname{Li}_2(y)}\;\frac1{1-y}\; dy
=\bbox[yellow]{\ -\frac 1{120}\pi^4\ }\ ,
\\
J_{12} &=
\int_0^1\log y\; \color{blue}{\operatorname{Li}_2(y)}\;\frac1{1+y}\; dy
=\bbox[yellow]{\ -\frac 1{480}\pi^4\ }\ ,
\end{aligned}
$$

---

Up to some point, integrals are manipulated using the "usual" properties of
integrals. The solution is given up to referenced results. However, afterwards, also a symbolic point of view is taken, key words are multiple zeta values (MZV) and generalized polylogarithms.

---

We will use first relations from the [wolfram dilog page](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/Dilogarithm.html) to split the wanted $J$ into pieces.
For instance the relation $(6)$ is useful:
$$
\tag{6}
\begin{aligned}
\operatorname{Li}_2(-y) 
- \operatorname{Li}_2(1-y)
+\frac 12 \operatorname{Li}_2(1-y^2)
&=-\frac {\pi^2}{12} - \log(+y)\log(1+y)\ ,
\\
\operatorname{Li}_2(+y) 
- \operatorname{Li}_2(1+y)
+\frac 12 \operatorname{Li}_2(1-y^2)
&=-\frac {\pi^2}{12} - \log(-y)\log(1-y)\ .
\end{aligned}
$$
Now subtract to get rid of the dilog computed in $(1-y^2)$,
we obtain a way to express the dilog of $-y$ in terms of the dilog
in $y$, $1\pm y$, and arguably simpler products of logarithms.
Our $y$ runs in $[0,1]$, so we replace tacitly $\log(-y)$ by $\log y$, and pass to the real part of all expressions involved.
(Equalities in the real part only, so modulo $i\Bbb R$ are denoted by $\equiv$.)
From the above we obtain:
$$
\tag{$\dagger$}
\operatorname{Li}_2(-y) 
\equiv
\color{blue}{\operatorname{Li}_2(y)}
+
\color{brown}{\operatorname{Li}_2(1-y)
-
\operatorname{Li}_2(1+y)}
+
\color{green}{\log(y)\log\frac{1-y}{1+y}}\ .
$$

---

Note that we may have used $(5)$ from *loc. cit.* instead,
which apparently should be simpler, since it involves only two dilogs, so we replace in integral involving $\operatorname{Li}_2(-y)$
with an other one involving $\operatorname{Li}_2(1+y)$, and products of
$\log$'s. Using $(6)$ there are three dilogs appearing! Why? It turns out that the integral corresponding to $\operatorname{Li}_2(y)$ is "*clean*", and the difference $\operatorname{Li}_2(1+y)-\operatorname{Li}_2(1-y)$ also leads to a "*clean*" integral. Details follow.

---

We will use $(5)$ from *loc. cit.* to isolate the real part from
$$
\operatorname{Li}_2(1+y)
=
\underbrace{
-\operatorname{Li}_2(-y)
+\frac{\pi^2}6
-\log (-y)\log(1+y)}_{\Re \operatorname{Li}_2(1+y)}
\pm i\pi\log(1+y)\ ,\qquad y\in[0,1]\ ,
$$
where the monodromy is hidden in the imaginary part,
and we try to avoid powers of $\operatorname{Li}_2(1+y)$
in calculus, to mix different branches.
Below, taking the real part is pointing tacitly to this dilog of $(1+y)$, $y\in[0,1]$, where $1+y$ leaves the disk of convergence of the dilog.
In particular,
$\Re \operatorname{Li}_2(2)
=\Re \operatorname{Li}_2(1+1)
=-\operatorname{Li}_2(-1)+\frac {\pi^2}6
=\frac{\pi^2}4$.

---

For these simpler products, for the integrals that
are obtained from it is convenient to also introduce the notation:
$$
\Bbb J_{abc,def}=
\Bbb J\binom{a\ b\ c}{d\ e\ f}
=
\int_0^1
\frac {\log^a(1-y)\log^b(y)\log^c(1+y)}{(1-y)^d(y)^e(1+y)^f}\; dy\ .
$$
A similar notation is introduced in
the arXiv the article [Au1], page 1, of Kam Cheong Au,
as mentioned in the other answer of . We use two references, to his articles, the information can be also extracted from the Book [Z], Chapter 13:

- [Au1](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1910.12113.pdf) ,
- [Au2](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2007.03957.pdf) ,
- [Z] Multiple Zeta Functions, Multiple Polylogarithms And Their Special Values,  Jianqiang Zhao.

In the notations from [Au1] we have

- $i_{abc0}=\Bbb J_{abc,100}$,
- $i_{abc1}=\Bbb J_{abc,010}$,
- $i_{abc2}=\Bbb J_{abc,001}$.

Considering the results from [Au1], uur stand point is
that for powers $d,e,f$ between $0,1$,
and small values of the "weight" $w=a+b+c+1$ ($w\le 4$) we can compute / look up in a table for $\Bbb J_{abc,def}$, and take the value as a present.
Note that a  partial fraction decomposition reduces the cases for $(d,e,f)$
among $110$, $101$, $011$, $111$ to the simpler $100$, $010$, $001$.
In  fact, we will soon do a similar split for
$\frac 1{1-y^2}=\frac 12\left(\frac 1{1-y}+\frac 1{1+y}\right)$.

Then we have from $(\dagger)$ a linear dependence between the **real part** of the following integrals $J, J_1,J_2,J_3$:
$$
\begin{aligned}
J &=
\int_0^1\log y\; \operatorname{Li}_2(-y)\;\frac1{1-y^2}\; dy\ ,\text{ the integral of interest,}
\\
J_1 &=
\int_0^1\log y\; \color{blue}{\operatorname{Li}_2(y)}\;\frac1{1-y^2}\; dy
=\bbox[yellow]{\ -\frac 1{192}\pi^4\ }\ ,\text{ a clean value to be shown below,}
\\[3mm]
J_2 
&=
\Re
\int_0^1\log y\; 
\color{brown}{\Big(
\operatorname{Li}_2(1+y)
-
\operatorname{Li}_2(1-y)
\Big)}
\;\frac1{1-y^2}\; dy
\\
&=
\frac 12
\Re\int_0^1\log y\; 
\left(
\frac{\operatorname{Li}_2(1+y)}{1+y}
+
\frac{\operatorname{Li}_2(1+y)}{1-y}
-
\frac{\operatorname{Li}_2(1-y)}{1+y}
-
\frac{\operatorname{Li}_2(1-y)}{1-y}
\right)\; dy
\\
&\equiv
-\frac 12
\int_0^1
\Big(\Re\operatorname{Li}_2(1+y)\Big)'\Re\operatorname{Li}_2(1+y)\; dy
-
\frac 12
\int_0^1
\Big(\operatorname{Li}_2(1-y)\Big)'\operatorname{Li}_2(1-y)\; dy
\\
&\qquad\qquad
+
\frac 12
\int_0^1
\underbrace{\frac{\log y}{1-y}}
_{=(\ +\operatorname{Li}_2(1-y)\ )'}
\Re\operatorname{Li}_2(1+y)\; dy
-
\frac 12
\underbrace{\int_0^1\frac{\log y}{1+y}}
_{\sim (\ -\Re\operatorname{Li}_2(1+y)\ )'}
\operatorname{Li}_2(1-y)\; dy
\\
&=
-\frac 14\Bigg[\ (\Re\operatorname{Li}_2(1+y))^2\ \Bigg]_0^1
-\frac 14\Bigg[\ \operatorname{Li}_2(1-y)^2\ \Bigg]_0^1
\\
&\qquad\qquad
+\frac 12\Bigg[\ \operatorname{Li}_2(1-y)\Re\operatorname{Li}_2(1+y)\ \Bigg]_0^1
\\
&=
-\frac 14\Big[\ 
(\Re \operatorname{Li}_2(2))^2 - \operatorname{Li}_2(1)^2\ \Big]
-\frac 14\Big[\ 
0-\operatorname{Li}_2(1)^2 \ \Big]
+\frac 12\Big[ \ 0-\operatorname{Li}_2(1))^2 \ \Big]
\\
&=-\frac 14\cdot
(\Re \operatorname{Li}_2(2))^2
=\bbox[yellow]{\ -\frac {\pi^4}{64}\ }\ ,
\\[3mm]
J_3
&=\int_0^1\log y\cdot  
\color{green}{\log y\log\frac{1-y}{1+y}}\cdot \frac1{1-y^2}\; dy
\\
&=\frac 12\Bbb J_{120-021,100+001}\qquad\text{(with a linear split
w.r.t. the symbolic indices)}
\\
&=
\frac{53}{1440}\pi^4
+\frac 16\pi^2\log^2 2
-4\operatorname{Li}_{\color{red}4}\left(\frac 12\right)
-\frac 72\log(2)\,\zeta(3)
-\frac 16\log^42\ .
\end{aligned}
$$
Then we obtain a formula for $J$, from $J=J_1-J_2+J_3$,
$$
\bbox[lightyellow]{\qquad
J=
\frac{17}{360}\pi^4
+\frac 16\pi^2\log^2 2
-4\operatorname{Li}_{\color{red}4}\left(\frac 12\right)
-\frac 72\log(2)\,\zeta(3)
-\frac 16\log^42\ .
\qquad}
$$

---

---

**MZV and symbolic computations.** I will try to collect some facts, see the above references. The problem with MZV's (*M*ultiple *Z*eta *Values) is that all articles go in the direction of using the (Hopf-)algebraic part of them,
there are not so many examples - so that the many MSE integrals that appear still look like each one is a world for itself. Dictionary and formulas follow.

We fix a ("chromatic") level $N$. For our needs, $N=1$ and $N=2$ are enough.
We deal with iterated integrals, computed for functions
$f,g,\dots,h$,

- identified in notation with the right objects to be taken, which are forms
  $f(t)\; dt$,
  $g(t)\; dt$, ... , $h(t)\; dt$ -
  which are defined on some interval (or manifold parametrized interval) $\gamma$. In our case (the manifold is $\Bbb R$ and) $\gamma=[0,1]$. So i will write the integral limits $0,1$ below.
  $$
  \operatorname{It}(f,g,\dots,h)
  =\int_0^1 f(t)\; dt\int_0^t g(u)\; du\dots \int_0^? h(v)\; dv\ ,
  $$
  where the question mark stays for the previously used integration variable.
  So we integrate $f\otimes g\otimes\dots\otimes h$ on the simplex
  $1\ge t\ge u\ge\dots\ge v\ge 0$.
  Write
  $$
  \operatorname{It}_\gamma(f,g,\dots,h)
  $$
  if needed in order to integrate on an other path, e.g. $[0,t]$ with a dynamic $t$.
  We are mainly interested in functions $f,g,\dots,h$ in a very small world of functions. Here are they:
- level $N=1$,
  $\frac 1t$ and $\frac 1{1-t}$ - written as forms $\frac{dt}t$, $\frac{dt}{1-t}$,
- level $N=2$,
  $\frac 1t$ and $\frac 1{1-t}$ and $\frac 1{-1-t}$ - written as forms $\frac{dt}t$, $\frac{dt}{1-t}$, $\frac{dt}{-1-t}$,
- and with a general $N$ we associate $\mu$ the primitive root of unity which is $\exp$ of $2\pi i/N$, and the alphabet contains now $\frac 1t$ and all fractions $\frac 1{\mu^{-k}-t}=\frac{\mu^k}{1-\mu^k t}$.

Iterated integrals look then like (non-commutative) words in this alphabet.

Since the alphabet is so small, and the the characters in it so complicated,
we really use established "simple letters".
For level $1$, in a first decade the convention was to take $0$ for $1/t$ and $1$ for $1/(1-t)$. Then further levels came in, and an other notation was with $a$ and $b_0$ instead, as in the references [Au1], [Au2], [Z]. The index zero of $b_0$ points to the power $k=0$ of the unit $\mu$ to be taken. So for a general $N$ we have $b_0$, $b_1$, ... till $b_{N-1}$. My convention below is to use

- $A$ for $0$, and $a$, and explicitly $1/t$,
- $B$ for $1$, and $b_0$ in level $N$, and explicitly $1/(1-t)$,
- $C$ for $b_1$ in level two $N=2$, and explicitly $-1/(1+t)$.

$$
\begin{array}{|c|c|}
\hline
\text{Words in few symbols} & \text{Tuples of few functions}\\\hline
A &\frac{dt}t\\\hline
B=B_0 &\frac{dt}{1-t}\\\hline
B'=B_1 &-\frac{dt}{1+t}\\\hline
X=\text{Alphabet }\{A,B,C\}^* & \Omega=\text{Alphabet in }\frac{dt}t,\ \frac{dt}{1-t},\ -\frac{dt}{1+t}\\\hline
X\text{-word} & \Omega\text{-word}\\\hline
X\text{-word }w & \Omega\text{-word often also written }w\\\hline
\int_0^1 w\in\Bbb R & \operatorname{It}(w)=\operatorname{It}_{[0,1]}(w)\in\Bbb R\\\hline
\operatorname{Li}_w(t)=\operatorname{Li}(w,t)=
\int_0^t w & \operatorname{It}_{[0,t]}(w)\\\hline
\int_\gamma w  & \operatorname{It}_\gamma(w)\\\hline
\bbox[lightyellow]{\qquad
\int_\gamma w\cdot \int_\gamma w'
=
\int_\gamma w\ ш\ w'\qquad}   & 
\operatorname{It}_\gamma(w)\operatorname{It}_\gamma(w')
=
\operatorname{It}_\gamma(w \ ш\ w')\\\hline
ш\text{ is the shuffle product of words} &\\\hline
\int_t^1 A^n & \frac 1{n!}(-1)^n\log^n t\\\hline
\int_0^t B^n & \frac 1{n!}(-1)^n\log^n (1-t)=\frac 1{n!}\operatorname{Li}_1(t)^n\\\hline
\int_0^t C^n & \frac 1{n!}(-1)^n\log^n (1+t)=\frac 1{n!}\operatorname{Li}_1(-t)^n\\\hline
\operatorname{Li}(B,t) & \operatorname{Li}_1(t) =-\log(1-t)=\int_0^tB=\int_0^t\frac{dt}{1-t}\\\hline
\operatorname{Li}(AB,t) & \operatorname{Li}_2(t) =\int_0^t\frac {\operatorname{Li}_1(t)}{t}\;dt
\\ &=\int_0^t\frac {dt}t\int_0^t\frac {du}{1-u} = \operatorname{It}_{[0,t]}\left(\frac 1t,\frac1{1-t}\right)
\\\hline
\operatorname{Li}(AAB,t) & \operatorname{Li}_3(t) 
=\int_0^t\frac {\operatorname{Li}_2(t)}{t}\;dt = \operatorname{It}_{[0,t]}\left(\frac 1t,\frac 1t,\frac1{1-t}\right)
\\\hline
\operatorname{Li}(\underbrace{AA\dots AB}_{n\text{ letters}},t) & \operatorname{Li}_n(t) 
\\\hline
Z(s) = Z_0(s)=\underbrace{AA\dots AB}_{s\text{ letters}} &\\
Z'(s) = Z_1(s) = \underbrace{AA\dots AB'}_{s\text{ letters}} &\\\hline
Z_j(s)= \underbrace{AA\dots AB_j}_{s\text{ letters}} &\\\hline
s =(s_1,s_2,\dots,s_d)\text{ poly-index} & s =(s_1,s_2,\dots,s_d)\in\Bbb N_{>0}^d\\\hline
j =(j_1,j_2,\dots,j_d)\text{ poly-index} & j =(j_1,j_2,\dots,j_d)\in(\Bbb Z/N)^d\\\hline
\Delta j=(j_1-0, j_2-j_1,\dots,j_d-j_{d-1}) & \\\hline
x =(x_1,x_2,\dots,x_d)\text{ poly-argument} & x =(x_1,x_2,\dots,x_d)\\\hline
\mu =(\mu,\mu,\dots,\mu)\text{ as poly-argument} & \mu =(\mu,\mu,\dots,\mu)\\\hline
\prod Z(s,j) =\prod_j Z_j(s)\\
=Z_{j_1}(s_1)\dots Z_{j_d}(s_d) &\\\hline
& 
\displaystyle
\zeta(s) = L(s)=L(s,1)\\
&
\displaystyle
=\sum_{n_1>\dots >n_d\ge 1}\frac 1{n_1^{s_1}\dots n_d^{s_d}}\\\hline
& 
\displaystyle
L(s,x)=\sum_{n_1>\dots >n_d\ge 1}\frac {x_1^{n_1}\dots x_d^{n_d}}{n_1^{s_1}\dots n_d^{s_d}}\\\hline
\int_0^1\prod Z(s,j) & L(s, \mu^{\Delta j})\\\hline
\end{array}
$$

We are computing integrals in this answer. Some part of the manipulations is purely algebraic, e.g. hidden in the shuffle algebra. Making the computations on the symbolic side is easier. Often, a MZV is obtained, and relations in the MZV-algebra are finally used to obtain the "usual" (even) powers of $\pi$, and zeta-values of odd arguments.

There are some convergence issues, for some words, but we neglect them here.

---

---

Let us illustrate the above with some computations.
Words will occur, corresponding to functions/forms to be considered inside
an iterated integral.

- We hate any $B=B_0$ at the beginning of a word, and in this case, we replace
  $B^m w_1 w'$ by $-\frac 1m$ times $B^{m-1}w_1(B\ ш\ w')$.
  In other words, we "formally take" the last $B$ in the prefix $B^m$ and move it through the word
  $w_1w'$ at any place after each letter, first time after the first character $w_1$, then after the first two, and so on, the last entry time we see $B$ at the last place. The factor $-1/m$ correspond to the fact that there is a full $B$-prefix $B^m$.
- We hate any $A$ at the end of a word, and in this case, we replace
  $w'w_dA^m$ by $-\frac 1m$ times $(w'\ ш\ A)w_dA^{m-1}$.
  In other words, we "formally take" the first $A$ in the suffix $A^m$ and move it through the word
  $w'w_d$ at any place beyond $w_d$.

The iterated integrals and the $L$-values are extended to follow this rule.

---

The computation of $J_1$. The following part $J_{11}$ of $J_1$ is simpler,
because only $y$ and $1-y$ appear, so the symbolic part involve only $A,B$:
$$
\begin{aligned}
J_{11}
&=
\int_0^1\log y\; \operatorname{Li}_2(y)\;\frac1{1-y}\; dy
\\
&\overset{\text{up to }\pm}
=
\int_0^1\frac {dy}{1-y}
\left(\int_y^1\frac{du}{u}\right)
\left(\int_0^y\frac{du}{u}\int_u^1\frac {dv}{1-v}\right)
\\
&=
\int_0^1 B\int_0^t A\ ш\ AB
\\
&=
\int_0^1 B( \color{blue}{A}\ ш\ AB )
\\
&=
\int_0^1 
(
B\color{blue}{A}AB 
+
BA\color{blue}{A}B 
+
BAB\color{blue}{A}
)
=2\int_0^1\color{brown}{B}AAB+\int_0^1 \color{brown}{B}ABA
\\
&\qquad\text{ move $\color{brown}{B}$ from the first place behind}\\
&=
-2\int_0^1
(A\color{brown}{B}AB + AA\color{brown}{B}B
+ AAB\color{brown}{B})
-\int_0^1 
(A\color{brown}{B}BA + AB\color{brown}{B}A+ ABA\color{brown}{B})
\\
&=
-3\int_0^1ABAB
-4\int_0^1AABB
-2\int_0^1ABB\color{blue}{A}
\\
&\qquad\text{ move $\color{blue}{A}$ from the last place to the left}\\
\\
&=-3\int_0^1ABAB
-4\int_0^1AABB
+2\int_0^1(AB\color{blue}{A}B + A\color{blue}{A}BB + \color{blue}{A}ABB)
\\
&=-\int_0^1ABAB=-\int_0^1Z(2)Z(2)
\\
&\overset{\text{up to }\pm}=\int_0^1 Z(2,2)=\zeta(2,2)
\\
&\qquad\text{ recall $\zeta(k)\zeta(n)=\zeta(k,n)+\zeta(n,k)+\zeta(n+k)$, use $k=n=2$}
\\
&=\frac 12(\zeta(2)^2-\zeta(4)) = \frac 1{120}\pi^4\ .
\end{aligned}
$$
Numerical check, pari/gp:

```
? intnum(y=0, 1, log(y) * dilog(y) / (1 - y))
%20 = -0.8117424252833536436370027724058759270810632139390451807622321615830904621402266349176822269562749379
? Pi^4/120
%21 = 0.8117424252833536436370027724058759270810632139390451807622321615830904621402266349176822269562749379
```

---

The computation of the remained part $J_{12}$  from $J_1$ follows,
we have algebraically a similar situation, but together with $y$ and $1-y$ there appears also $1+y$, so the symbolic part involve  $A,B$ and also the $2$-chromatic piece $B'$:
$$
\begin{aligned}
J_{12}
&=
\int_0^1\log y\; \operatorname{Li}_2(y)\;\frac1{1+y}\; dy
\\
&\overset{\text{up to }\pm}
=
\int_0^1\frac {dy}{1+y}
\left(\int_y^1\frac{du}{u}\right)
\left(\int_0^y\frac{du}{u}\int_u^1\frac {dv}{1-v}\right)
\\
&=
\int_0^1 B'\int_0^t A\ ш\ AB
\\
&=
\int_0^1 B'( \color{blue}{A}\ ш\ AB )
\\
&=
\int_0^1 
(
B'\color{blue}{A}AB 
+
B'A\color{blue}{A}B 
+
B'AB\color{blue}{A}
)
=2\int_0^1\color{brown}{B'}AAB+\int_0^1 \color{brown}{B'}ABA
\\
&\qquad\text{ move $\color{brown}{B'}$ from the first place behind}\\
&=
-2\int_0^1
(A\color{brown}{B'}AB + AA\color{brown}{B'}B
+ AAB\color{brown}{B'})
-\int_0^1 
(A\color{brown}{B'}BA + AB\color{brown}{B'}A+ ABA\color{brown}{B'})
\\
&=
-2\int AB'AB-2\int_0^1AA(BB'+B'B)
-\int_0^1(AB'B+ABB')\color{blue}{A}
-\int_0^1ABAB'
\\
&\qquad\text{ move $\color{blue}{A}$ from the last place to the left}
\\
&=
-2\int AB'AB-2\int_0^1AA(BB'+B'B)
+\int_0^1\color{blue}{A}A(B'B+BB')
\\
&\qquad
+\int_0^1A\color{blue}{A}(B'B+BB')
+\int_0^1AB'\color{blue}{A}B
+\int_0^1AB\color{blue}{A}B'
\\
&=-\int_0^1AB'AB=-\int_0^1Z_1(2)Z_0(2)
\\
&\overset{\text{up to }\pm}=\int_0^1 Z_{(1,0)}(2,2)=L_{(1,1)}(2,2)
\\
&=\zeta(\bar 2,\bar 2)
\\
&\qquad\text{ use $\zeta(\bar k)\zeta(\bar n)=\zeta(\bar k,\bar n)+\zeta(\bar n,\bar k)+\zeta(n+k)$, $n+k$ even,
for $n=k=2$}
\\
&\qquad\text{ recall $\zeta(\bar 2)=-\frac 1{1^2}+\frac 1{2^2}-\frac 1{3^2}+\frac 1{4^2}\pm \dots=-\left(1-\frac 2{2^2}\right)\zeta(2)=-\frac1{12}\pi^2$,
}
\\
&=\frac 12(\zeta(\bar 2)^2-\zeta(4)) 
= \frac 12\pi^4\left(\frac 1{12^2}-\frac 1{90}\right)
= -\frac 1{480}\pi^4\ .
\end{aligned}
$$
Numerical check, pari/gp:

```
? intnum(y=0, 1, log(y) * dilog(y) / (1 + y))
%25 = -0.2029356063208384109092506931014689817702658034847612951905580403957726155350566587294205567390687345
? lindep([% , Pi^4])
%26 = [480, 1]~
? -Pi^4/480
%27 = -0.2029356063208384109092506931014689817702658034847612951905580403957726155350566587294205567390687345
```

---

I have to stop here, typing kills my energy, and the MO-web-interpreter hangs. It remains to show the formula for
$J_3$, again the same symbolic computations apply. Similar examples are in [Au1], [Au2]. Initially, i considered the case to be simpler to put down on the paper, but - as the result shows, there must be a mess in weight four words that show up. If a particular aspect is of interest, i will fill in. The notation $\Bbb J$ was introduced to conquer better the situation, but...

---

---

**Later EDIT:**
The formula for $J_3$ can be obtained in a similar symbolic framework, and then checked in pari/gp, i will do this now in order to answer some comments. The fomula for $J_3$ is
$$
J_3
=
\int_0^1\log^2 y\;\log\frac{1-y}{1+y}\cdot \frac1{1-y^2}\; dy
$$
so is a linear combination of integrals of
$\frac 1{1\pm y}\log^2y\frac 1{1\pm y}$. Working symbolically, $\frac 1{2!}\log^2y$
corresponds to $A$, and  $\frac 1{1-y}$, $-\frac 1{1+y}$ respectively to $B=B_0$, $B'=B_1$. We use the indices $j,k$ in the $B$-symbols to cover all four cases. We use $\mp_j$ for $(-1)^{j-1}$, so $\mp_0=\mp$. Then:
$$
\begin{aligned}
J_{3jk}&:=\int_0^1\frac1{1-\mp_j y}\log^2 y\;\log(1\mp_k y)\; dy
\\
&\overset{\text{up to }\pm}=
\int_0^1 B_j(2A^2\ ш\ B_k)
=2\int_0^1B_j(B_kAA +AB_kA+AAB_k)\qquad\text{(right-$A^2$-moves)}
\\
&=-\int_0^1(AB_jB_kA+B_jAB_kA)+2\int_0^1B_jAB_kA+2\int_0^1B_jAAB_k
\\
&=-\int_0^1AB_jB_kA+\int_0^1B_jAB_kA+2\int_0^1B_jAAB_k\qquad\text{(right-$A$-moves)}
\\
&=+\int_0^1(2A^2B_jB_kA + AB_jAB_k)   - \int_0^1(AB_jAB_k + 2B_jAAB_k) +2\int_0^1B_jAAB_k
\\
&=+2\int_0^1A^2B_jB_k=2\int_0^1Z_j(3)Z_k(1)
\\
&= 2L_{3, 1}(\ (-1)^j\ ,\ (-1)^{j+k}\ )\ ,
\\
&\qquad\qquad\text{ and we use the values:}
\\
&\qquad L_{3,1}(1,1) = \zeta(3,1)=\frac 14\zeta(4)=\frac 1{360}\pi^4\ ,\\
&\qquad L_{3,1}(1,-1) = \zeta(3,\bar 1)\ ,\\
&\qquad L_{3,1}(-1,1) = \zeta(\bar 3,1)\ ,\\
&\qquad L_{3,1}(-1,-1) = \zeta(\bar 3,\bar 1)\ ,\\
&\qquad\qquad\text{ and we have:}\\
\frac 12J_{300}
&=-\zeta(3,1)=-\frac 1{360}\pi^4\ ,
\\
\frac 12 J_{310}
&= +\zeta(\bar 3,\bar 1)
=
\frac 1{180}\pi^4 +\frac 1{12}\pi^2\log^2 2 - 2\operatorname{Li}_4\left(\frac 12\right)  - \frac 1{12}\log^4 2\ ,
\\
-\frac 12J_{301}
&=+\zeta(3,\bar 1)=
\frac{19}{1440}\pi^4 -\frac 74\log 2\;\zeta(3)
\ ,
\\
-\frac 12 J_{311}
&= -\zeta(\bar 3,1)
=
\frac 1{48}\pi^4 +\frac 1{12}\pi^2\log^2 2 - 2\operatorname{Li}_4\left(\frac 12\right)
  -\frac 74\log2\;\zeta(3) - \frac 1{12}\log^4 2\ ,
\end{aligned} 
$$
and this gives finally the claimed value for $J_3$,
$$
J_3=\frac 12(J_{300} +J_{310}-J_{301}-J_{311})
=\frac {53}{1440}\pi^4 +\frac 16\pi^2\log^2 2
- 4\operatorname{Li}_4\left(\frac 12\right)
-\frac 72\log 2\;\zeta(3)
- \frac 16\log^4 2
\ .
$$

---

*Note:* The sum $\zeta(3,\bar 1)+\sum(\bar 3,\bar 1)$ can be also extracted
from [Au2], Example 3.2, where $-\zeta(3,\bar 1)-\sum(\bar 3,\bar 1)$ is given (with no further reference).
The value $\zeta(3,1)=\frac 14\zeta(4)$ can be obtained from
$\zeta(2)^2=\int_0^1AB\cdot\int_0^1 AB=\int_0^1AB\ ш\ AB
=2\int_0^1ABAB + 4\int_0^1AABB=2\int_0^1Z(2)Z(2)+4\int_0^1Z(3)Z(1)=2\zeta(2,2)+\zeta(3,1)$.
The book [Z] has in Appendix, Euler sums for lower weights, page 537, also formulas relating these MZVs. All weight four alternating MZV are listed.

Comment: Something’s I didn’t understand fully because I don’t know too much about MZV,still(+1)

Comment: Feel free to ask, i'll try to give hints or references. The idea is to isolate first the "universe" of functions to be integrated. Our universe is small here, we integrate $1/x$ or $1/(1-x)$ and obtain $\log x$ and the first polylog, Li${}_1=-\log(1-x)$. Then use recursively already constructed polylog's to get new ones by integrating. If we have Li${}_n(y)$, then we integrate Li${}_n(y)/y$ from $0$ to $x$ to get Li${}_{n+1}(x)$. So everything in the universe is a Chen *iterated integral*. This is easy, and i appologize for taking space for it, the idea is now to write everything as iterated..

Comment: .. integral. Problems may appear when under the $\int_0^1$ we have a product of pieces defined by iterated integrals, e.g. Li$_2(y)\cdot$Li$_5(y)$. Each factor, piece is an iterated integral. There are two "pieces". How to write everything as one iterated integral?! We use the shuffle product "sha", the formula from the table is the one involving $$\int_\gamma w\int_\gamma w'$$ on the LHS, and on the RHS we have the one iterated $\int_\gamma$ from the shuffle product of the smaller ingredients of each of the two pieces. One more point: We pass from integrals to multiple zeta values..

Comment: This is the equality written in a very symbolic manner:$$\int_0^1\prod Z(s,j)=L(s, \mu^{\Delta j})\ .$$The LHS has a symbolic character, $$Z(s,j)=Z(s_1,j_1)\dots Z(s_d,j_d)$$and on the RHS we have a multiple zeta value, computed in "powers of $\mu$". Let us assume $\mu=1$, $N=1$, no chromatic first. (See also the examples in Au2, §3, page 7, my $A$ is $a$, my $B=B_0$ is $b_0$ there, and my $L$ is there Ł.) There is no index-delta, no index in fact. We only the $(A^?B)$ parts, call them $Z(?+1)$, pass to a $Z$ of a poly-argument, it is a poly-zeta, and we try to work now in this world.

Comment: I don't understand, **why did you accepted an answer with a wrong result?**. Obviously, the dilogarthm integral is not  $$J=
\frac{17}{360}\pi^4
+\frac 16\pi^2\log^2 2
-4\operatorname{Li}_2\left(\frac 12\right)
-\frac 72\log(2)\,\zeta(3)
-\frac 16\log^4 2$$. The correct value is $$I=
\frac{17}{360}\pi^4
+\frac 16\pi^2\log^2 2
-4\operatorname{Li}_4\left(\frac 12\right)
-\frac 72\log 2\,\zeta(3)
-\frac 16\log^4 2$$ There is a difference in the polylogarithm. I have checked the development of the **wrong answer** and it is not a typo. It raises internally with a wrong application of MZV

Comment: @Martin.s I guess user dan_fulea is going to return back to you the bounty. Amendments after the expiration date, if they are made, have no value.

Comment: @JorgeZuniga OK, i will compute explicitly also the integral $J_3$ to get the right result. The edit page was frozen more than dozen times. The value was obtained by asking `pari/gp` for a lindep, and in the lindep there were specified only "weight four values", so `polylog(4, 1/2)` was there. If it is all about the bounty, i can of course give it back.

Comment: @dan_fulea, sorry, but this is unfair and it is a bad explanation. Two comments, the first about the attitude. The bounty may be important, but more important is the attitude. It's not about whether you are able to give it back. You must give it back. We all hope you are aware of that. You put a result that is wrong and incomplete as you acknowledge by yourself.

Comment: @dan_fulea, The second comment is not as important as the first one above since it is about technical details of your answer. 1.- You should not only add Li(4,.), you have to eliminate Li(2,.), a serious error that creeps in from the beginning. 2.- When using LINDEP to search for integer relations, you can find a formula, but we all know that the LLL algorithm, unlike other algorithms like WZ, the formula found does not result proven and that is a fatal flaw as any mathematician understand.

Comment: @Martin.s I am still waiting an explanation about why did you accepted an answer with a wrong result.

Comment: @JorgeZuniga The formula for the final result is now corrected, as promised. Details to the computations of $J_3$ are also added, so that the result has a base in the available space. It was a typo, belive it, since the expected result must be a weight four MZV. The quadrilog was already in the older MSE 2412715 mentioned by Jack D'Aurizio. The $J_3$-computation leads to a linear combination of all $\zeta(3,1),\ \zeta(\bar 3,1),\ \zeta(3,\bar 1),\ \zeta(\bar 3,\bar 1)$. The sum of the two $\bar 3$-ZV appears in [Au2], Example 3.2. i had to check+compare, my attention was on the $\pi^4$-term.

Answer (score 4):

Use Package MultipleZetaValues (Version 1.2.0) for Mathematica, developed by Kam Cheong Au,

You can get it and install using this command

```
    PacletInstall[CloudObject["https://www.wolframcloud.com/obj/pisco125/MultipleZetaValues-1.2.0.paclet"]]
```

It gives this closed form straightwise

[image]

I guess this result is proven (it is not conjectured) as you can check it following Au publications in the arXiv [[**1**]](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1910.12113), [[**2**]](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2201.01676), [[**3**]](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2007.03957) and [[**4**]](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2212.02986).

---

From the comments, the OP is searching a developed ("chisel and hammer") answer. I will bring such answer for both, **A.-** the integral question and **B.-** the trigamma series that originated it.

We use the following references

[[**5**]](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1911.12155.pdf) Ming Hao Zhao "On logarithmic integrals, harmonic sums and variations" arXiv:1911.12155v13 [math.CA]

This provides a wide compendium of methods and techniques to solve Euler Sums, polylog integrals and much more from undergraduate to deep research specialized level.

[**6**] Valean, C.I.: (Almost) Impossible Integrals, Sums, and Series, Springer, Cham, First Edition (2019).

[**7**] Valean, C.I.: More (Almost) Impossible Integrals, Sums, and Series, Springer, Cham, First Edition (2023)

**A.-** The polylog integral $$I=\int_0^1\frac{\log(y)\,Li_2(-y)}{1-y^2}\,dy$$ We use these generating functions, [7] pg. 398 and 406,  valid for $|x|<1$, $k\ge 1$ and $k\in \mathbb{N}$ $$g_k(x)=\frac{Li_k(x)}{1-x}=\sum_{n=1}^\infty x^n H_n^{(k)}\quad\textrm{and}\quad \bar{g}_k(x)=\frac{Li_k(-x)}{1-x}=-\sum_{n=1}^\infty x^n \bar{H}_n^{(k)}$$ where $H_n^{(k)}=\sum_{m=1}^n m^{-k}$ and $\bar{H}_n^{(k)}=\sum_{m=1}^n\ (-1)^{m-1} m^{-k}$ with $H_0^{(k)}=\bar{H}_0^{(k)}=0$. So, $$I=\frac{1}{2}\int_0^1\left[g_2(-x)+\bar{g}_2(x)\right]\cdot\log(x)\,dx $$ but $\int_0^1 x^n \log(x)\,dx = -1/(n+1)^2$, $n\in\mathbb{N}\cup\{0\}$. Therefore, by dominated convergence to commute sums and integral, we have $$I=\frac{1}{2}\sum_{n=1}^\infty (-1)^{n-1}\frac{H_n^{(2)}}{(n+1)^2}+\frac{1}{2}\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{\bar{H}_n^{(2)}}{(n+1)^2}$$ $$I=\frac{1}{2}\sum_{n=1}^\infty (-1)^{n-1}\frac{H_{n+1}^{(2)}-\frac{1}{(n+1)^2}}{(n+1)^2}+\frac{1}{2}\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{\bar{H}_{n+1}^{(2)}-(-1)^n\frac{1}{(n+1)^2}}{(n+1)^2}$$ $$I=\frac{1}{2}\sum_{n=1}^\infty (-1)^{n}\frac{H_n^{(2)}}{n^2}+\frac{1}{2}\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{\bar{H}_n^{(2)}}{n^2}$$. Now apply summation by parts on the second sum with $a_n=1/n^2$ and $b_n=\bar{H}_n^{(2)}$, this gives $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{\bar{H}_n^{(2)}}{n^2}=\frac{17}{720}\pi^4+\sum_{n=1}^\infty (-1)^{n}\frac{H_n^{(2)}}{n^2}$$ Therefore $$I=\frac{17}{1440}\pi^4+\sum_{n=1}^\infty (-1)^{n}\frac{H_n^{(2)}}{n^2}$$ The right hand sum is a classical result for an alternating harmonic sum. For instance [6] pp. 309-310, also [5] pg. 88 Table 9.2 Euler Sums 7th row under Weight 4 ES (2;-2). It gives $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty (-1)^{n}\frac{H_n^{(2)}}{n^2}=\frac{17}{480}\pi^4+\frac{1}{6}\pi^2\log^2(2)-\frac{1}{6}\log^4(2)-\frac{7}{2}\zeta(3)\log(2)-4Li_4\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)$$ Finally $$I=\frac{17}{360}\pi^4+\frac{1}{6}\pi^2\log^2(2)-\frac{1}{6}\log^4(2)-\frac{7}{2}\zeta(3)\log(2)-4Li_4\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)$$

**B.-** The polygamma series $$S=\sum_{n=1}^\infty(-1)^{n-1}\psi_1^2(n)$$ where the trigamma function (we use a subscript index) is $\,\psi_1(z)=\sum_{k=0}^\infty\,1/(k+z)^2$ satisfies this recurrence $\psi_1(2n-1)=\psi_1(2n)+1/(2n-1)^2$ which will be used together with $\,\psi_1(n+1)=\zeta(2)-H_n^{(2)}$. Writing $S$ as $$S=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\psi_1^2(2n-1)-\psi_1^2(2n)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\left[2\frac{\psi_1(2n)}{(2n-1)^2}+\frac{1}{(2n-1)^4}\right]$$ $$S=2\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{\psi_1(2n)}{(2n-1)^2}+\frac{\pi^4}{96}=2\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{\zeta(2)-H_{2n-1}^{(2)}}{(2n-1)^2}+\frac{\pi^4}{96}$$ $$S=\frac{5}{96}\pi^4-2\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{H_{2n-1}^{(2)}}{(2n-1)^2}=\frac{5}{96}\pi^4-\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{\left[(-1)^{n-1}+1\right]H_n^{(2)}}{n^2}$$ The alternating sum we already have it above. The monotone sum is also a classical result for a weight 4 Euler Sum. See [5](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2212.02986) pg. 88 Table 9.2 Euler Sums 5th row under Weight 4 ES (2;2). It gives  $$\,\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{H_n^{(2)}}{n^2}=\frac{7}{360}\pi^4$$ Joining all pieces, $$S=\frac{49}{720}\pi^4+\frac{1}{6}\pi^2\log^2(2)-\frac{1}{6}\log^4(2)-\frac{7}{2}\zeta(3)\log(2)-4Li_4\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)$$

Comment: This is closed form not an answer

Comment: @Martin.s It's very confusing what you're looking for if not a closed form for the integral.

Comment: You didn't get it. I'm asking what I can learn from a response given by Mathematica software

Comment: @Martin.s, Thanks, but I think (and many readers as well, I guess) that this result is exactly what you were asking for. Anyway Mathematica has a command to decompose computation into steps if you want to learn how this result was obtained. Also the links I left provide the details. I do not see how you want to go further the question you have made.

Comment: @CarloBeenakker, Fixed, check if it works now please.

Comment: Thank you, @Jorge Zuniga, for the response. Unfortunately, I don't have Mathematica, so I can't use the decompose command

Comment: The links you provided are challenging for me as an undergraduate student to comprehend. I'm seeking a conjectured closed form instead

Comment: Copied solution of coronel loan valean?

Comment: Actually not. As the references that I placed indicate it, this is a mix-up of methods of Zhao's paper (mainly) and Valean's books. Summation by parts to evaluate $I$ is a technique used by Valean and many others. In $S$ sum of odd terms equal to sum of monotone and alternating is a basic technique. I used a couple of known weight 4 sums that were taken from Zhao's tables. The proof was short, correct, complete, in-time and pretty clear.